# adb shell commands with su -c gives Permission denied (phone is rooted)

Tags: android, shell, adb, root

I have the following issue.

I have a rooted phone, and I want to update a file of an application. When I manually copy my file FILENAME to the phone via `adb push`, and get an `adb shell` and root credentials, I can copy $FILENAME to APP_DIR/$FILENAME without any problem.

However, after the `adb push` I try to do it with logging into the shell via `adb shell su -c`, I have given a permission denied message :S

My WORKING example:

```
adb push myfile /data/local/tmp/
adb shell
> su
> # cp /data/local/tmp/myfile /data/data/MYAPP/files/myfile
```

My NOT WORKING example:

```
adb push myfile /data/local/tmp/
adb shell su -c "cp /data/local/tmp/myfile /data/data/MYAPP/files/myfile"
/system/bin/sh: can't create /data/data/MYAPP/files/myfile: Permission denied
```

As a naive other solution, I tried to do without copy commands and used `cat myfile > /data/data/MYAPP/files/myfile` but still have the same message :S

Thanks for considering my request

Comment: What does `adb shell su -c "id"` give? To be honest, this doesn't look like a programming question, but a matter of how `su -c` works under whatever method you used to root the device. You might get better help from an Android forum.

Comment: Hi, it gives me back this:
`uid=0 gid=0`
And I also get this when do `adb shell` and then `su` and `id`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution a bit based on the comments.
So, even though I am root and I own the file (or some other process, but I can delete the file `touch` a new one), it was a typical permission problem.
So the file looked like this when issuing `ls -l`

```
-rw-r--r--    1  0    0         8901 Sep  6 22:09 myfile
```

So, simply using

```
adb shell su -c "chmod 755 /data/data/MYAPP/files/myfile"
```

gave the right permissions and using `cat` instead of `cp` works well.
(`cp` does not give error either but for some reason, the file is not updated)

Comment: It's actually device/android version dependent! On my Redmi 8A with Android 9, it works, but on my Redmi Note 4 with Android version 7, it does not :|